# How to detect bluetooth headset connection in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection, profile, headset

I tried example code google refers as below to detect connected bluetooth devices

```
BluetoothHeadset mBluetoothHeadset;


// Get the default adapter
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

// Establish connection to the proxy.
mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(context, mProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);

private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mProfileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
    public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
            mBluetoothHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) proxy;
        }
    }
    public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
            mBluetoothHeadset = null;
        }
    }
};

// ... call functions on mBluetoothHeadset
```

But I got the following problems:

1. mBluetoothHeadset is only available inside onServiceConnected. I use getConnectedDevices to detect live bluetooth headset. but if I place the code below
   List  ConnectedDevices = mBluetoothHeadset.getConnectedDevices();
   out of onServiceConnected, running program lead always crash. What's wrong here?
   is there any possibility to use mBluetoothHeadset value outside onServiceConnected ? like the example show? Or May I trans some parameter/value from onServiceConnected to outside?
2. Actually the example codes don't work. i have to place additional code after mProfileListener:
   if (mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(this, mProfileListener,BluetoothProfile.HEADSET)==false) { ....
   What's the reason? or what's wrong with my code?
3. From system log the code seems work, but when I run it, program stay in onServiceConnected, never go to onServiceDisconnected, or outside if no other action the user perform(e.g press a confirm button). What's wrong?